# Are my answers correct? (finding intercepts, asymptotes, and extrema)

Tags: calculus, analytic-geometry

Are my answers correct?

[image]

a) (0, 4/3) and (2,0) and (-2, 0)

b) Horizontal asymptote: $y = 3$, Vertical asymptotes: $x = 3, x = -3$

c) Extremum is at $(0, 4/3)$, maximum.

Comment: Yes, your answers are correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes**, all of the answers are correct. In future, maybe try and show your work as well, just in case there is a mistake? (This is an answer because I am answering the original question.)